# Java array is being rewrited :(

Tags: java

I´ve got a problem with my java project. I need to delete element from array and that´s taken care of. But the problem is that even though it removes the element (which I checked in debugging), when I click on the button, as far as i know, it basically rewrites the array so the fact that i removed the element doesn´t even matter. Any suggestions?

```
public class Words {

    Random r = new Random();
    public String[] poleSlov = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"};

    public String chooseRandomWord() {
        int tmp = r.nextInt(poleSlov.length);
        String p = poleSlov[tmp];

        String[] result = new String[poleSlov.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = poleSlov[((i < tmp) ? i : i + 1)];
        }

        poleSlov = result.clone();

        return p;
    }
}

private void btnNoveSlovoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    Words s = new Words();
    labSlovo.setText(s.chooseRandomWord());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`btnNoveSlovoActionPerformed()` creates a new `Words` instance, having a new `poleSlov` array. Since `s` is a local variable, after `btnNoveSlovoActionPerformed()` returns, the object it refers to is no longer accessible.

One possible fix is to call `chooseRandomWord()` on the current instance :

```
private void btnNoveSlovoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
{                                             
    labSlovo.setText(chooseRandomWord());
}
```

Comment: that´s what i know, but how to fix it? :D

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the actual String `poleSlov` is always the same. When a new instance of Words is created, `poleSlov` is redeclared with the same contents. I'd advise thinking about how you can edit this String's contents.